# The Exponent isn't Logical

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was drawing up some thoughts on: $54,200,000$ being written in scientific notation. Why would it be $5.4\times10^1$? Wouldn't it be to the $5^\text{th}$ power since there are five zeros?

Comment: Hint: What is $5.42\times 10^7$ in expanded form?

Comment: From $5.4$, how many times do you need to shift the decimal point to the right until you get your initial number ?

Comment: Well to answer the first person, it's not 10^7 it's to the 1st power.

Comment: To answer the second person, 4 spaces, no?

Comment: I edited what I thought was supposed to be a $7$ because that made the question make sense.  $5.42\times10^1=54.2$.

Comment: The 1 is clearly wrong, and most likely a typo.

Comment: Oh, I see, never mind. I'm doing the whole thing in reverse without realizing it. Okay, it's 6 spaces but 7 if we want the decimal. So 7? 10^7, of course.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar: I don't see what doesn't make sense about it... It makes perfect sense. The work may be done wrong, but it's a perfectly logical question. It's just asking HOW did I get that answer, and if that answer was wrong, a user would tell me the right and tell my why mine was wrong. Other than that, it's a normal question.

Comment: Maybe, although doubtfully because there are two commas, the European convention is used, in which case $54,200 = 5,42\times 10^1$.

Comment: @GPerez: I hear you. Thanks for answering. But I'm not specifically referring tot he European way. I'm in New York. The final answer would be 5.4 x 10^7, right?

Comment: Yes that's correct

Answer (score 5):

The "seven" does not mean number of zeros. 10^7 means 10000000 or ten million. Now multiply 5.4 with ten million...

Answer (score 1):

54,200,000 in scientific notation would be 5.42E+7 as one has to move the decimal point 7 places to before the ten million place. The first value has to be greater than zero and less than 10.

As an alternative consider converting 1234 into scientific notation which should be 1.234E+3.

Comment: Makes sense, I was mistaken doing the complete opposite. I move actually sevens spacs, so wouldn't it be 5.4 x 10^7? Would that be my final answer or do I now multiply something?